# (CHECK) Cardinality of Terms in the Expansion of a Product of Multinomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, summation, factoring, multinomial-coefficients

> QUESTION: How many terms are there in the expansion of
>   $$(x+y)(a+b+c)(e+f+g)(h+i)$$

I'd like some help with this one, but I'd also like to discuss a method of generalization on the problem, namely how should one compute the cardinality of terms for something like this:

$$\Sigma_{i=0}^{\alpha_1}\zeta_{1_i}\cdot\Sigma_{i=0}^{\alpha_2}\zeta_{2_i}\cdots\Sigma_{i=0}^{\alpha_n}\zeta_{1_n}$$

Here each $\alpha_k$ is arbitrary, so there are any number of $\zeta_{j_i}$'s for each sum.

---

$$\text{How does this sound?}$$
$$\downarrow$$

---

Let us generalize the problem a bit. We are asked to find the cardinality of terms in the expansion of a product of multinomials. This can be represented in the following way:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha_0}\zeta_{0_i}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha_1}\zeta_{1_i}\cdots \sum_{i=0}^{\alpha_n}\zeta_{n_i}$$
Now, consider the product of two such multinomials, say
$$(\zeta_{0_0}+\zeta_{0_1}+\cdots+\zeta_{0_{\alpha_0}})(\zeta_{1_0}+\zeta_{1_1}+\cdots+\zeta_{1_{\alpha_1}}).$$
From this it is clear that the first term in the first multinomial---that is, $\zeta_{0_1}$--- will be multiplied by the $\alpha_1$ terms in the latter multinomial, and so there will thus far be $\alpha_1$ distinct terms generated from this process. Now, this process will be done on each of the $\zeta_{0_i}$'s exactly $\alpha_0$ times, so it is quite clear that the number of distinct terms generated from these processes is precisely $\alpha_0 \cdot\alpha_1$. By extension, this action could then be done to a third multinomial with $\alpha_2$ terms, and so by the above logic this would give $\alpha_0\cdot\alpha_1\cdot\alpha_2$ distinct terms in the final expansion of three such multinomials. From this we see that the cardinality of the terms in the expansion of a product of multinomials is
$$\prod_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_j,$$
so if we are asked to find the cardinality of the terms in the expansion of
$$(x+y)(a+b+c)(e+f+g)(h+i),$$
then we notice that from left to right we have that $\alpha_0=2$, $\alpha_1=3$, $\alpha_2=3$, and $\alpha_3=2$, which leads us to the conclusion that the desired cardinality is $\alpha_0\cdot\alpha_1\cdot\alpha_2\cdot\alpha_3=2\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 2=36$, namely there are exactly $36$ terms in the expansion of the expression above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get everything you need by using the fact that $(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_m)(y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_n)$ has $mn$ terms.

To show this, note that the terms are $x_1$ times stuff ($n$ terms), and $x_2$ times stuff ($n$ more terms, and so on, for a total of $\underbrace{n+n+\cdots +n}_{\text{$m$ times}}$; that is, $m$ copies of $n$.

Now you should be able to deal with $(x_1+\cdots+x_m)(y_1+\cdots +x_n)(z_1+\cdots+x_p)$. Multiplying out the first two sums gives you $mn$ terms, and therefore when you multiply by $z_1+\cdots +z_p$ you get a total of $(mn)p$.

And so on.

Comment: That doesn't seem immediately obvious to me. Would you mind proving it?

Comment: I see, so then the answer here is $\Pi_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i$, right?

Comment: What I wrote is the outline of a proof. In principle one should use induction, but it doesn't seem bothering with. Take something simple like $(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2+y_3)$ and multiply out. We get $(x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_1y_3)+(x_2y_1+x_2y_2+x_2y_3)$. I have done the same sort of grouping as in the second paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @Trancot: Thanks for the edit. I agreed too fast about the $\alpha_i$, did not notice your numbering started out at $0$. So we want $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\cdots (\alpha_m+1)$. Another way of seeing it, that may or may not appeal to you, is to replace all the variables by $1$. Each term of the expansion gives us a product of $1$'s, which is $1$. So the number of terms must be $(1+\cdots+1)(1+\cdots+1)\cdots(1+\cdots +1)$, where there are $\alpha_1+1$ $1$'s in the first bunch, and so on.

Comment: Fix your subscripts too...

Comment: There was a remaining typo that I just fixed, in the first line it was supposed to be $y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_n$. Am using a lousy monitor, can't see things clearly enough.

Comment: Yes... I meant $y_{\text{This needs to by an $n$}}$...

Comment: On the things you added: As I mentioned before, you have a product of sums of the type $\sum_{0}^\alpha \zeta_i$. Since you are starting the indexing at $0$, that means the sum has $\alpha +1$ terms. So the total number of terms has shape $\prod (\alpha_j+1)$.